# Python packaging: Generate a python file at installation time, have this work with tox

Tags: python, build, code-generation, setuptools, tox

I want to generate a python file at installation time.

I want this work with both `python setup.py develop`, `python setup.py install` and `pip install`. So far so good.

However I also want this to work with *tox*. This is where I am having problems.

The approach I using is to tweak the `develop` and `install` commands to generate source code in setup.py like so:

```
# make code as python 3 compatible as possible
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import subprocess
import setuptools
import os.path
import distutils.core

from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.install import install


# Build anltr files on installation
#   this is such a mess... it looks like there are
#   no common steps to develop and install

class AntlrDevelopCommand(develop):
    def run(self):
        compile_grammar()
        develop.run(self)

class AntlrInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        compile_grammar()
        install.run(self)

def compile_grammar():
    here = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
    package_dir = os.path.join(here, 'latex2sympy')
    subprocess.check_output(['antlr4',  'PS.g4', '-o', 'gen'], cwd=package_dir)

setuptools.setup(
    name='latex2sympy',
    version=0.1,
    author='august.codes',
    author_email='augustt198@gmail.com',
    description='Parse latex markup into sympy: suitable for programmatic modifcation',
    license='GPLv3',
    keywords='MIT',
    url='',
    packages=['latex2sympy'],
    classifiers=[
],
    install_requires=['antlr-ast',  'sympy'],
    cmdclass=dict(
        install=AntlrInstallCommand,
        develop=AntlrDevelopCommand),
    test_suite='nose.collector'
)
```

However `tox`'s method of installation seems to somehow run `setup.py` away from my source code and the magic blackbox that `tox` represents makes it kind of infuriating to work out what's going on.

The problem seems to be down to this voodoo magic which pulls in `setup.py` runs it via an `exec`.... for some reason.

```
Command "/home/tom/active/latex2sympy/.tox/py35/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-e698cucb-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lu2idbzz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/tom/active/latex2sympy/.tox/py35/include/site/python3.5/latex2sympy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-e698cucb-build/
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Running with -v -v -v -v
- Reruning the pip command manually
- Adding a `pdb.set_trace` (command hangs and I don't see output)
- Adding an ipython shell (ipython no installed even when in install_required)
- Running a `strace -F` this shows that `setup.py` is indeed in the expected location relative to the source code

**Things I've considered trying:**

- Creating a network backdoor shell at run time (too lazy)

Comment: Looks like tox legacy interpreter support to handle PEP 263 defines (`tokenize.open` implicitly calls `detect_encoding`) and changes MS newlines to *nix newlines. I would say this is an issue between pip (I assume that's what's mktemping the `pip-*-build` dirs) handing off to tox?

Comment: I imagine you want to use tox for testing, so would it be a problem to specify `usedevelop = True` in the tox.ini file? This is more of a workaround, but it may be enough for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

In the *tox.ini*-file of your project, you can add [commands](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-commands=ARGVLIST) to be run in the test environments. A simple example looks something like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py34,py35,py36

[testenv]
deps=
    pytest
    ; ... other dependencies
commands= 
    pytest --basetemp={envtmpdir} {posargs}
    ; Add your command here?
```

Is it possible for you to add a command to make tox do what you want? (The command will be run for **each of the** environments).